# Trying to use CountIfs worksheet function in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to search a range of data D8:D27 and count the number of entries that are greater than and less than two numbers that I have entered in F29 and F30 respectively.  I cannot get the function to work properly.  When I run it, it outputs 0 into L27 which is incorrect.  I believe I have a syntax error but I cannot figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

```
Private Sub Calculation()

Dim MySum1 As Double
Dim UCL1 As Double
Dim LCL1 As Double

UCL1 = Range("F29")
LCL1 = Range("F30")

MySum1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("D8:D27"), "> UCL1", 
Range("D8:D27"), "< LCL1")
Range("L27").Value = MySum1

End Sub
```

The sample data im using is below.  F29 is 235.500 and F30 is 230.500

It should be outputting 4, but I am getting 0 for some reason.

```
233.232
232.183
233.634
231.342
235.684
231.883
233.931
233.755
232.119
231.543
236.423
233.517
234.653
234.444
231.298
235.755
230.223
233.782
233.511
233.987
```

Comment: Looks like you should have ">" & CStr(UCL1) instead of "> UCL1"

Comment: I made the changes you mentioned and its still outputting 0.  I shared the data in the questions now so you can see exactly what im using.  I would like it to count any entries > 235.500 and < 230.500.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wait!  I think I figured it out.  The countif is looking for a number that satisfies both conditions, which is no possible so thats why its 0.  I need to seperate countifs, one for > and one for <.  Then Ill add them together.  Thanks for your help!